# how to divide a web page using divisions and how to give links between those parts of pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html page, having two div's.Left div contains all contents(INDEX of pages) with hyper-links.Now i want to display the content in the right div, that the user has clicked.In right div i have divided the page horizontally into 3 parts..10%,80%,10%.In that 80% horizontal div it shd display the content.I tried by using the target attribute in anchor tag, but it is not showing in that right div.How to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Are you trying to achieve a classic page navigation, an ajax navigation or an anchor navigation?

Comment: anchor navigation..if i click on the link,it shd display that file information in the right side..@chadocat

Comment: <a href="C:/Program Files/RUNNING.txt">file1</a>....if i give like dis in the left side..that txt file shd be displayed in the right side pane when clicking on that link..can u please provide code for this??

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This:

**css:**

```
div {
    width:90%;
    height:800px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:blue;
}
a {
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div id="one">Top of Page</div>
  <div id="two"><a href="#one">Go to Top</a></div>
  <div id="three"><a href="#two">Go to Two</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **Iframes**. Can refer this site to get started:  http://www.dtp-aus.com/frm_sets/frames.html